# Labeling feature with table using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, table

Is there a way to write an expression that puts the variables into a table like in the sample image?

I can do it manually like in the sample but I will be making about 150 maps, so it would be way more efficient to code in a label format.

[image]

Comment: have you checked help files of your version of Arc for 'Label expressions' or 'Building label expressions'?

Comment: Yes, but it has nothing about labeling with tables.  I've written label expressions to stack the text etc.., but I can't find any documentation of this even being possible in ArcMap.  I'm being asked to replicate the format of another map, which I suspect was made in Pro. I also suspect the tables were manually added as images, which is how I made the sample.